# $\rho OPT + k$ approximation for bin packing (Unpublished result of David P. Williamson)

Tags: np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, packing, extremal-combinatorics, chernoff-bound

I am currently stuck on [Exercise 5.12](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf) in this book, which is apparently an unpublished result of David P. Williamson according to the book notes.

The problem asks to use randomized rounding and first fit algorithm to give a randomized rounding for 1D bin packing that uses at most $\rho OPT + k$ bins, for some $\rho<2$ and constant $k$.

I decided to go with rounding the configuration LP which is as follows. Suppose there are $m$ possible sizes of the elements to be packed with $b_1$ of size $s_1$, $b_2$ of size $s_2$, ..., and $b_m$ of size $s_m$. Let $\bf T_1, ..., T_n$ denote all the possible (possible exponential) configurations of bins satisfying $\sum_j t_{i,j}s_j \leq 1$. Then the LP is

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}  & \displaystyle\sum_{j}x_j \\
\text{subject to}& \displaystyle\sum_{j}x_j{\bf T_j} \geq {\bf b} \\
& x_j \geq 0
\end{array}

is a relaxation. Even though there is an exponential number of variables (one for each configuration), it is possible to solve this LP in polynomial time within an additive error of $1$ using the ellipsoid method. So suppose we now have the (near)-optimal solution ${\bf x}^\ast$ with at most $m$ non-zero entries. Let $z^\ast = \sum_{j}x_j^\ast$

Next, I thought about sampling $\rho z^\ast $ configurations independently with probability $\frac{x_j}{z^\ast}$. Suppose they are $\bf R_1, R_2, ..., R_{\rho z^\ast }$ with ${\bf G} = \sum_i \bf R_i$
However, now we need to show that the constraints are satisfied with high probability. To do this, observe that

$$\mathbb{E}({\bf G})=\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i}{\bf R_i})= \rho z^\ast \mathbb{E}({\bf R_i})\geq \rho {\bf b}$$

So for any size $i$, we can use standard Chernoff bound to bound that the constraint is not satisfied, or namely that

$$Pr(G_i \leq b_i) = Pr(G_i \leq (1-(1-\frac{1}{\rho})(\rho b_i))\leq e^{-\frac{\rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 b_i}{3}}$$

**And this is where I am stuck.** The bound $b_i\geq 1$ is not strong enough to enable using the union bound to prove that all the inequalities ($m$ of them) are satisfied with high probability.

The only way I see fixing this issue is to only consider $b_i\geq \Omega(\log m)$ and handle all the sizes with $b_i< O(\log m)$ separately, but that would affect the number of bins by an extra additive $O(m\log m)$ which isn't constant.

Comment: As the problem says you should try to use both rounding and a fixing algorithm. Estimate the expected total size of the items that are not satisfied and then pack them using first fit.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Thanks, I think I figured it out. Added an answer just for completion.

Answer (score 2):

Using Chandra's hint, I think I got the idea. We bounded the probability:

$$Pr(G_i \leq b_i) \leq e^{-\frac{\rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 b_i}{3}}$$

Now consider an item of size $s_i$ that was left. It was left out because we didn't sample a configuration that contains it. This happens with probability

$$(1-\sum_{j:{\bf T_j} \text{ contains item }i}\frac{x_j}{z^\ast})^{\rho z^\ast}\leq e^{-\rho}$$

Hence, using linearity of expectation, we expect at most $e^{-\rho}b_i$ items of size $s_i$ to be left out from the first sampling.

Now the final thing we need to do is to bound the **expected** total size of the remaining elements that were left out from the sampling. The bound is

$$\sum_{i=1}^m e^{-\frac{\rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 b_i}{3}} \times e^{-\rho}b_i\times s_i \leq  e^{-\rho - \frac{ \rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 }{3}} OPT$$

We can then use any algorithm (say first fit) to approximate the remaining items in at most $$ 2e^{-\rho - \frac{ \rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 }{3}} OPT $$
bins. Thus, we have used at most (on expectation)

$$(\rho + 2e^{-\rho - \frac{ \rho(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^2 }{3}})OPT + 1$$

bins. If we set $\rho \in (1, 1.64)$, then the algorithm is a $\Delta OPT+1$ ($\Delta<2$) approximation. For example, setting $\rho=1.2$, we get a $1.785OPT + 1$ approximation.